# NodeJs FindbyId in an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I want to retrieve data from a specific local object

```
var db=[
{
    "_id": "543adb9c7a0f149e3ac29438",
    "name": "user1",
    "email": "user1@test.com"
},
{
    "_id": "543adb9c7a0f149e3ac2943b",
    "name": "user2",
    "email": "user2@test.com"
}
```

]

i did this to find a specific user only by id, and in Postman i always get error 500

```
app.get('/msg/:id',(req, res) =>{
    db.findById(req.params.id, function(err, dba) {
            if (err)
            res.send(err)
            res.json(dba)
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi! Share you code please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

findById is a method of Mongoose library, not a method of JavaScript objects. If you want to use it, you should implement it by yourself in JavaScript objects

If db is a local object and not a db connection, you can use find

```
app.get('/msg/:id',(req, res) =>{
    var dba = db.find(element => element._id == req.params.id);
    if(dba) res.json(dba);
    else res.sendStatus(404)
});
```

Comment: It wil be good if you can explain OP that why `findById` can't be used in local objects. Also, OP has done some error handling. Will you add that too.

Comment: findById is a method of Mongoose library, not a method of JavaScript objects. If you want to use it, you should implement it by yourself in JavaScript objects

Comment: I am not asking asking to explain it to me. I was asking to explain that in your answer.

Comment: Hey sir, this is not working, i'm getting the same error error 500, i'm doing a restful api wthout mongodb ( in a local object ), so when i go to http://localhost:3000/msg/543adb9c7a0f149e3ac29438 i got error 500

Comment: Check you nodejs console.

Comment: your last Edit worked like a charm, may god bless you thank you. @VipinKumar

Comment: Thanks for your improvement @VipinKumar